# Why does a variable change?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am new to JavaScript, so I may have messed up something simple.

I am currently practicing JS on codewars, and have the prompt of:

*The goal of this exercise is to convert a string to a new string where each character in the new string is "(" if that character appears only once in the original string, or ")" if that character appears more than once in the original string. Ignore capitalization when determining if a character is a duplicate.*

Some examples are:

*"din"      =>  "((("*

*"recede"   =>  "()()()"*

*"Success"  =>  ")())())"*

*"(( @"     =>  "))(("*

Here is my attempt at the exercise:

```
function duplicateEncode(word){
  word = word.toLowerCase().split(''); 
  var tempWord = word
  var newWord = [];
  var ii = 0;
  
  while (tempWord.length>0){
    ii ++;
    tempWord.splice(0,1);
    
    if (tempWord.includes(word[ii])){
      newWord.push("(");
    } else {
      newWord.push(")");
    }
  }
  return(newWord.join(''));
}
```

The problem I am having occurs on

```
tempWord.splice(0,1);
```

as when that line is called, it also affects the variable "word".
Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: `tempWord = word` **does not** create a copy. You have two names referencing the same array.

Comment: `word` is an *array*, so `tempWord` is a reference to the same array. The assignment does not make a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var tempWord = word` Create a reference to the word array.

if you want to create a copy of the word array try this:

```
// ES6 way
const tempWord = [...word];

// older method
const tempWord = Array.from(word);
```